# Hidden file .env not copied using Docker COPY

Tags: linux, ubuntu, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have a Dockerfile and there is a syntax like this `COPY ["Gemfile", "Gemfile.lock", "Procfile", ".env", "/huginn/"]`

I use `RUN /bin/bash -l -c "ls -a"` to check file cope status, I find .env file doen't be copied to the image.

I change the .env file name to test.env and use `COPY ["Gemfile", "Gemfile.lock", "Procfile", "test.env", "/huginn/"]`, then it work, test.env is copied to the image.

Anyone know why is? And any solution can let docker support `COPY` .env file name?

Comment: A `.env` file should be copied by default, is the ls running in the same dir? `ls -a /huginn`?

Comment: The <src> path must be inside the context of the build; you cannot COPY ../something /something, because the first step of a docker build is to send the context directory (and subdirectories) to the docker daemon.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

If you have `.dockerignore` file then it might be you added to ignore hidden files like `.git`, `.vagrant` etc.

If `.dockerfile` ignoring hidden files then either you can enable to not ignore or change file name.

[For more info about .dockerignore file](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#dockerignore-file)

Comment: If the file is ignored the command will error `lstat .env: no such file or directory`

Comment: you're right, there is a `.dockerignore` file added to ignore hidden files `.env`, so I can't `COPY` the .env file, thanks for your help.

Comment: How do you enable to not ignore?

Comment: Why not showing an example?

Answer (score 23):

There is a statement in [.dockerignore file](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#dockerignore-file) documentation:

```
Note: For historical reasons, the pattern . is ignored.
```

[image]

Comment: The author is asking about a specific file: `.env`. I would expect that the note you mentioned is about `.` only, and not all files or folders that start with it (e.g. `.*`). Additionally, the documentation states: `A preprocessing step removes leading and trailing whitespace and eliminates . and .. elements using Go’s filepath.Clean. Lines that are blank after preprocessing are ignored.`

Answer (score 3):

share my dockerfile, it can work correctly now

```
FROM ruby:2.3

MAINTAINER Tomato <tsaohucn@gmail.com>

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive
ENV LANG C.UTF-8
ENV RAILS_VERSION 5.0.1

# install rails && bundler
RUN gem install rails --version "$RAILS_VERSION"

WORKDIR /huginn

# copy huginn config file
COPY ["Gemfile", "Gemfile.lock", "Procfile", ".env", "/huginn/"]
COPY lib/gemfile_helper.rb /huginn/lib/
COPY vendor/gems /huginn/vendor/gems

# run bundle install
RUN bundle install

# copy huginn
COPY . /huginn/
RUN ls -a
```

And there is a .dockerignore:

```
.git
tmp
log
doc
spec
media
.openshift
.bundle
vendor/bundle
db/*.sqlite3
public/system/*
coverage
.travis.yml
build_docker_image.sh
# Copied from .gitignore
*.rbc
*.sassc
.sass-cache
capybara-*.html
.rspec
!/tmp/.gitkeep
**.orig
rerun.txt
pickle-email-*.html
.idea/
.DS_Store
deployment/tmp
deployment/cookbooks
.vagrant
.*un~
.ruby-gemset
.ruby-version
manifest.yml
config/unicorn.rb
db/schema.rb
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue, here is an easy solution===>

Copy hidden files with exact directory path Like:-

Example:-
COPY path/.hidenfile destination_path

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had to explicitly copy the file to the image

Just adding this line in the Dockerfile solved my problem:

`COPY .env /app/`

Answer (score -3):

Your COPY syntax is wrong, this syntax is valid for ENTRYPOINT or CMD in a Dockerfile.

See the doc for COPY

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#/copy

Comment: It's valid syntax for COPY, the second form in the docco

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy :

COPY

COPY has two forms:

COPY [--chown=<user>:<group>] <src>... <dest>
COPY [--chown=<user>:<group>] ["<src>",... "<dest>"]