# Problem running a Docker container in Gitlab CI/CD

Tags: docker, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci, dvc

I am trying to build and run my Docker image using Gitlab CI/CD, but there is one issue I can't fix even though locally everything works well.

Here's my Dockerfile:

```
FROM <internal_docker_repo_image>
RUN apt update && \
    apt install --no-install-recommends -y build-essential gcc
COPY requirements.txt /requirements.txt

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir --user -r /requirements.txt

COPY . /src
WORKDIR /src
ENTRYPOINT ["python", "-m", "dvc", "repro"]
```

This is how I run the container:

`docker run --volume ${PWD}:/src --env=GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=<path_to_json> <image_name> ./dvc_configs/free/dvc.yaml --force`

Everything works great when running this locally, but it fails when run on Gitlab CI/CD.

```
stages:
  - build_image

build_image:
  stage: build_image
  image: <internal_docker_repo_image>
  script:
    - echo "Building Docker image..."
    - mkdir ~/.docker
    - cat $GOOGLE_CREDENTIALS > ${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/key.json
    - docker build . -t <image_name>
    - docker run --volume ${PWD}:/src --env=GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=<path_to_json> <image_name> ./dvc_configs/free/dvc.yaml --force
  artifacts:
        paths:
          - "./data/*csv"
        expire_in: 1 week
```

This results in the following error:
`ERROR: you are not inside of a DVC repository (checked up to mount point '/src')`

Just in case you don't know what DVC is, this is a tool used in machine learning for versioning your models, datasets, metrics, and, in addition, setting up your pipelines, which I use it for in my case.

Essentially, it requires two folders `.dvc` and `.git` in the directory from which `dvc repro` is executed.

In this particular case, I have no idea why it's not able to run this command given that the contents of the folders are exactly the same and both `.dvc` and `.git` exist.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5):

Your `COPY . /src` is problematic for the same reason as [Hidden file .env not copied using Docker COPY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42132475/hidden-file-env-not-copied-using-docker-copy). You probably need `!.dvc` in your `.dockerignore`.

Additionally, `docker run --volume ${PWD}:/src` will overwrite the container's `/src` so `$PWD` itself will need `.git` & `.dvc` etc. You don't seem to have cloned a repo before running these `script` commands.

Comment: This doesn't help, unfortunately. The strange thing is that the same Dockerfile and `docker run` yield expected results without Gitlab CI/CD, which I don't think would be the case if the issue was related to the `dockerignore` file. 

If I change this part  `--volume ${PWD}:/src` to anything else (except `src`),  the pipeline succeeds.

Comment: Thanks! This makes sense, but why does it work for the `docker run` without Gitlab CI/CD. The same command, different results.

Comment: My understanding is that `${PWD}` has all the files pushed to the repo so after mounting we effectively access this directory whenever `/src` is used inside the container. I might misunderstand how it really works of course, but the question remains: why does it work outside CI/CD?

Comment: @DonDraper I doubt the files are in the CI/CD since I don't see any clone step in your config so don't know what is/isn't included. You could try `ls -a`.

Comment: @casper.dci, `ls -a` shows that the current directory has all the necessary folders and files